# jquery method calls object method without '()'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){

    var model = function(){
        return {
            prop: function(){ return $('input').val(); }
        }        
    }();

    $('button').click(function(){
        console.log(model.prop);
        $('label').text(model.prop)      
    })

})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHvFk/22/)

check console output vs updated value in the html. How does it get returned value and not func's body, without the '()' call?

p.s. i mean, he calls model.prop and not model.prop()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `text()` accepts a callback function from which to derive the desired text.

http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text

If you pass it a string, it outputs that. If you pass it a function, it executes it and spits out the return value.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `text` method also accepts a function as a parameter and calls it internally.

Look at [this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) where it accepts a function as the parameter.

> function(index, text) Type: Function() A function returning the text
>   content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set
>   and the old text value as arguments.

**If you want to print the function body then** you may call [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) to print the function body

```
$('label').text(model.prop.toString())
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QL2dj/)

Comment: +1. And, it might be added, for a `console.log`-like behavior, OP could call `.text(model.prop.toString())`

Answer (score 2):

Because you can pass a function to nearly every jQuery method to dynamically create values for the single elements in the collection. From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text):

> **.text( function(index, text) )**
>
> `function(index, text)` Type: Function()
>
> A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery 1.4, if the passed parameter to $.text is a function, jQuery will execute it and use its result as text.

http://api.jquery.com/text/